# How to design this type of dashboard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. How can I create this type of dashboard in flutter?
2. What is the name of this type of dashboard?

I have added images for reference.

[image: example-1]

[image: example-2]

Comment: list inside a tab view;

Comment: I don't want this tab view ..I only want a homepage with this type of design.Please provide a link to this type of design.I want to learn how to do these type of material  designs  ?

Comment: just  a list view in flutter will do

Comment: that dashboard is from gridview

Comment: any link to learn ?? how to do???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should be useful

[image: sample]

```
class SO extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SOState createState() => _SOState();
}

class _SOState extends State<SO> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Foodie"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: foods.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var food = foods[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(food.name),
            subtitle: Text(food.detail),
            leading: FlutterLogo(),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(food.isFav ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
              onPressed: () => {
                setState(
                  () {
                    food.isFav = !food.isFav;
                  },
                )
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Food> foods = [
  Food('food 0', 'about food 0'),
  Food('food 1', 'about food 1'),
  Food('food 2', 'about food 2'),
  Food('food 3', 'about food 3'),
  Food('food 4', 'about food 4'),
  Food('food 5', 'about food 5'),
  Food('food 6', 'about food 6'),
];

class Food {
  final String name;
  final String detail;
  bool isFav;

  Food(this.name, this.detail, {this.isFav = false});
}
```

---

EDIT:

for the dashboard background

[image: dashboard]

---

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[dashBg, content],
      ),
    );
  }

  get dashBg => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.deepPurple),flex: 2,),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),flex: 5,),
        ],
      );

  get content => Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(32),
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Center(child: Text('create your content inside this')),
  );
}
```

---

extending this here with code

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[dashBg, content],
      ),
    );
  }

  get dashBg => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.deepPurple),
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
            flex: 5,
          ),
        ],
      );

  get content => Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            header,
            grid,
          ],
        ),
      );

  get header => ListTile(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
    title: Text(
      'Dashboard',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    subtitle: Text(
      '10 items',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    trailing: CircleAvatar(),
  );

  get grid => Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: .90,
            children: List.generate(8, (_) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[FlutterLogo(), Text('data')],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

gives

[image: dash_sample]